# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occured on a send

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to run/debug locally my cloud project, but service bus connection keeps crashing with error:

```
<15:46:59> MessagingFactory successfully created
<15:47:39> Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.. 

....
   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
    An existing   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)}
```

Also I receive this error when using Service Bus Explorer tool.

When deploy to cloud everything works ok, service bus connection is ok.

Can anyone help me with this? what could be the reason?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several reason leading to such error so you may check the following

- You have configured the settings correctly.
- Firewall in your system allows the connection (protocol, host & port)
- DNS servers configured in your network are able to resolve the host.
- Your ISP is not blocking your connection due to any reason

Since there is no fixed solution for your error, you may have to work a little hard to figure out the actual issue. You may also find some useful information from the log files if enabled.

Comment: That can confirm that the first check is OK unless changed from the vendor. Other's may still need to verify as last 2 are likely to happen.

Comment: Great find, it is really tough to troubleshoot such issues.

Comment: For anyone searching:  **Also check your proxy settings.**  We have proxy set by group policy.  It's not supposed to apply to servers, but this one was in the wrong AD group.  Hence I didn't see any packets on the router, it was all getting intercepted/closed by the Squid server.  Took me forever to figure that out.

Answer (score 33):

Maybe the problem is with the SSL certificate validation protocol. Try this to force the latest protocol type.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: This saved me. Dotnet 4.7 seems have a different behavior that default TLS is not 1.2

Comment: Oh thank you!!  I was using sendgrid that started enforcing TLS 1.2 and their sample code does NOT mention setting this.  I added this and it started working and stopped the forcibly closed error.