# Need to enable TLS1.2 in server environment and disable TLS1.0 & 1.1

Tags: c#, tls1.2, webrequest

We have disabled TLS1.0 and 1.1 in our server, Enabled only TLS1.2. But we are getting the below exception.

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

We tried the following solution.

1. [The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occured on a send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510416/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occured-on-a-send)

.Net framework version is 4.6.2.
Any solution for this?

Comment: Which Windows version are you using? TLS1.2 should be used by default in all Windows versions still in support. In .NET, 4.6.2 and later automatically use the OS's encryption. This means you should be able to use TLS1.3 in Windows 10 1903 and later

Comment: In older, unsupported Windows versions, you need to add the appropriate update or make some Registry tweaks to enable TLS1.2

Comment: Windows Server 2019 @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Windows Server 2019, and in code we have set
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
before WebRequest @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: That line *enables* older protocols, when you said you want to *dis*able them. It's not needed anyway. Use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to check the protocol negotiation between your client and the server. In `CONNECT` calls, the Request contains the parameters offered by the client and the response the parameters accepted by the server.

Comment: So, shall we remove  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: This *weakens* encryption but doesn't prevent TLS1.2. Use Fiddler to see what's going on. If the server requires TLS1.3, you won't be able to connect. If due to incorrect registry settings you disabled TLS1.2, you won't connect. Check the CONNECT calls in Fiddler to see what's actually going on

Comment: BTW HttpWebRequest is obsolete, replaced by HttpClient. In .NET Core, it's actually a compatibility wrapper over HttpClient. And in .NET 6, it's marked as Obsolete and planned for removal in a future version. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-5.0#remarks) have a strong warning against using it in new code

Comment: You can try to isolate the problem. Create a simple console application in .NET Core or .NET Old, with a single call to that server, without any other tweaks. Does one of them work? Does it work on one machine but not another? If this works on other machines, it means something's wrong with the machine settings

Comment: Try to connect to `https://www/google.com` too. Google, like most major sites, requires TLS1.2. If you can connect to it but not the remote server, the problem is that server.

Answer (score -1):

Just place in the Startup of your application:

```
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 ;
```

Comment: This says `don't use TLS1.3 even if it's available`. It's not needed in .NET 4.6.2 because that version and every one after it,uses the best available encryption provided by the OS. If the OS doesn't support TLS1.2, hard-coding the setting won't help

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos The question was, only TLS 1.2 is enabled...

Comment: Which means that line shouldn't be needed at all. It was needed only in 4.5.x which *didn't* use TLS1.2 by default.

Comment: I had the same problem on windows server 2019 and .NET4.7. The only solution was to set the SecurityProtocol to TLS12. The framework did not use TLS1.2 or higher by default.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
Currently I am using 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

Comment: @ChrisBerlin
Our .net framework version is 4.6.2